# Django / Python send_email() function results in "Temporary failure in name resolution" error

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean, ubuntu-20.04

**Introduction**

I'm hosting a Django application with Nginx and Gunicorn on a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 20.04) with a domain name and mail bought at NameCheap.

I will use the following example values in my code snippets:

```
domain = example.com
email = info@example.com
droplet ip address = digital_ocean_droplet_ip
```

I have configured everything as described in [Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) and [Secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Everything is working as it should however when my application tries to send a mail I get the following error:

```
gunicorn[97049]:    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
gunicorn[97049]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1043, in __init__
gunicorn[97049]:     SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
gunicorn[97049]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
gunicorn[97049]:     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
gunicorn[97049]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
gunicorn[97049]:     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
gunicorn[97049]:     new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
gunicorn[97049]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 1049, in _get_socket
gunicorn[97049]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
gunicorn[97049]:     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gunicorn[97049]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
gunicorn[97049]:     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
gunicorn[97049]: socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

[socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KUpM.png)

**Django settings.py**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('example.com,www.example.com,digital-ocean-droplet-ip')

EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_USE_SSL=False
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST="mail.privateemail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER="info@example.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="***"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL="info@example.com"
```

**Django views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

# Send confirmation email
send_mail(
    # Subject
    'Subject',
    # Message
    'Message',
    # Sender
    'info@example.com',
    # Receiver
    [receiver@email.com],
    fail_silently=False
)
```

**Digital Ocean DNS records** [Documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/dns/how-to/manage-records/)

```
Type        Hostname                            Value                                       TTL (seconds)

SRV         _autodiscover._tcp.example.com      privateemail.com.example.com                43200
CNAME       autoconfig.example.com              privateemail.com.                           43200
CNAME       autodiscover.example.com            privateemail.com.                           43200
CNAME       mail.example.com                    privateemail.com.                           43200
TXT         example.com                         v=spf1 include:spf.privateemail.com ~all    3600
MX          example.com                         mx2.privateemail.com.   (priority 10)       14400
MX          example.com                         mx1.privateemail.com.   (priority 10)       14400
A           example.com                         digital_ocean_droplet_ip                    3600
A           www.example.com                     digital_ocean_droplet_ip                    3600
NS          example.com                         ns1.digitalocean.com.                       1800
NS          example.com                         ns2.digitalocean.com.                       1800
NS          example.com                         ns3.digitalocean.com.                       1800
```

**NameCheap Custom DNS** [Documentation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10375/2208/how-do-i-link-a-domain-to-my-digitalocean-account/)

```
ns1.digitalocean.com
ns2.digitalocean.com
ns3.digitalocean.com
```

When I ping the mail server from the droplet (mail.privateemail.com) I get this result.

```
telnet mail.privateemail.com 587

Trying 198.54.122.60...
Connected to mail.privateemail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 PrivateEmail.com prod Mail Node
ehlo privateemail.com
250-mta-14.privateemail.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 81788928
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 STARTTLS
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**Question**

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this, because the rest of the application is running fine? I have a feeling that this issue is caused by DNS but I have no clue how to fix it and I feel like I've tried just about everything.

Hopefully someone can help me because I'm a little bit lost and don't know how to continue.. Thanks in advance!

*I've tried the following settings so far without any success:*

```
EMAIL_USE_SSL       True, False (with the according ports)
EMAIL_USE_TLS       True, False (with the according ports)
EMAIL_PORT          465 port for SSL, 25/587 port for TLS
EMAIL_HOST          mail.privateemail.com
                    mx1.privateemail.com
                    mx2.privateemail.com
                    mail.example.com
                    example.com
                    digital_ocean_droplet_ip
```